# How do we use "Back in" properly?

Tags: word-usage

I'd like to know if the phrase "My dogs back in Brazil still remember me.", or would it be better in another way, like just "in Brazil"?

I've been living in another country for an year, and the dogs recognized me in a video call. I want to tell in English that my dogs in Brazil remembered me after a long time.

Comment: back in implies that you are from that location or previously lived there........and that you left the dogs behind

Answer (score 1):

I would say *back in* is appropriate here.

*Back* implies that you have lived there previously and left the dogs there. Whereas, if you omit the word *back in*, it could imply you just left the dogs for a relatively short period of time (I would say less than a month) and that you went on holiday. So *back in* does add meaning here.